# How do I check how many digits my answer has?

Tags: java, algorithm, floating-point, double, iteration

I'm trying to find the most precise value by calling a method many times. How can I check when the nth iteration will give a value of precision 8 digits. My method returns a double each time I call it, but I want to stop calling it when the result has 8 digits of accuracy in it.

For example, if I call the method getValue() 20 times, and on the 20th time it has an answer that has 8 digits, how do I check the answer and stop the code?

My method is too long to post, so a general explanation should suffice.

The Problem is as follows:

> Use the power method to calculate the largest eigenvalue of the Leslie matrix A. The iteration of the power method should stop when you get 8 digits of accuracy.The Leslie Matrix Model can be written as
>
> ```
> n(k + 1) = An(k), k = 0, 1, 2,... and with some n(0) given.
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`double` is never going to be precise enough in this way. The only way to know the accuracy of your answer is by doing a mathematical analysis of the operation you're doing and stopping when the error is guaranteed to be less than a certain amount.

However, there is a little bit of a trick if you know your analysis is going to converge. You can compare successive values, and see how large the difference is. Here's some pseudocode:

```
while(true) {
    nextValue = computeNextValue(previousValue);
    if(Math.abs(previousValue - nextValue) < ERROR_THRESHOLD) {
        break;
    }
    previousValue = nextValue;
}
```

---

@user58697 makes a great point in the comments:

> Even if the sequence converges, successive difference may stop the process too early. Knowing the convergence rate is vital.

Keep this in mind when writing your program.

Comment: Oh, I see! So I need to mathematically figure out when my method guarantees that the answer is exactly 8 digits?

Comment: @Shan Make sure you read the edit. The second paragraph is a much easier solution than the first. Forget my first version

Comment: Even if the sequence converges, successive difference may stop the process too early. Knowing the convergence _rate_ is vital.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I do not believe that there is a generic answer. How do you know that the answer 7.9999999 is more precise than 8.0 (which could be 8.00000000000000) ? It probably depends very much on the problem you want to solve, I guess.

Comment: That much I can post.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following hack to check the fractional part. Here is the complete code  -

```
public class FractionCheck{

     public static void main(String[] args){

        int length1 = findFractionLegth(423423.98476527);
        int length2 = findFractionLegth(428294.31231);

        System.out.println(length1);
        System.out.println(length2);

     }


     public static int findFractionLegth(double number){

        String numberStr = Double.toString(number);
        String fractionalStr = numberStr.substring(numberStr.indexOf('.')+1);

        return fractionalStr.length();
     }

}
```

The `findFractionLegth(double number)` method calculate the fractional part of a `double`.

Comment: This won't work. Let's say his method returns 6.123456789996 and the *correct* answer is is 6.12345679000000 your method won't stop when it should.

Comment: great finding. I didn't consider it